# phpfox facebook-connect in manage setting went missing

Tags: facebook, phpfox

New in phpfox and needed to make facebook login I looked for facebook-connect to what is said in this tutorial **[here](http://phpfoxdemo.ceofox.com/faqs/view/15/enabling-facebook-connect/)**, found it and was just browsing a bit more to check if it was similar to fb login. Later I came to look for it again but seems facebook-connect disappeared in the AdminCP Manage settings. Checked history and found page but when I go there I get this **"This setting group has no available settings."** tried to use find missing settings but no luck. How do I get facebook-connect option settings back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The how to enable Facebook Connect tutorial is [here](http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/83/enabling-facebook-connect/), if you still don't get it you probably disabled the Facebook module, if that is enable you should contact the Support department, perhaps you edited a template?